# Why would Landlord lease to Tenant when represented by agent, but not directly to Tenant when unrepresented?

Tags: real-estate-leasing

This "change of heart" has happened many times to our family and friends, in both Commercial and Residential Leasing. Tenant is trying to lease. After Tenant approached Landlord directly without any Real Estate Agent, Landlord rejected Tenant, even before any negotiation! Landlord replied

> I am afraid that we have no available space for you at the moment. I shall keep in touch with you if any space opens up for you.

Then Tenant hires an estate agent. The agent found the exact same listings with the exact same Landlord, and sent Landlord the exact same financial and personal information about Tenant. But now, Landlord is  willing to lease that exact same vacancy to Tenant! Landlord is ready to negotiate.

**Why would Landlord lease to only Tenants represented by Estate Agent?

Why did Landlord lie to Tenant, when Tenant was unrepresented?**

Comment: Have you asked the landlord? There may be many reasons, none of which people here would know.

Comment: @littleadv No. I don't want to antagonize Landlord. I don't want Landlord to feel I think Landlord is lying.

Comment: I imagine in some jurisdictions they are free to choose to only do business with those that use an agent. Perhaps they just had some bad experiences with people not using agents in the past and have decided it's a good first screening step for potential tenants, that'd be my guess as to their reasoning, but that's all we can do is guess at it.

Comment: "I am afraid that we have no available space **for you at the moment**" -- that was not a lie, if the landlord was unwilling to rent to that tenant under those circumstances (unrepresented). It was arguably misleading in implying that a space could possibly become available with the passage of time without a change in the tenant's circumstances, or in implying that the landlord was not at the same time seeking other tenants to whom they *would* be willing to rent. But it was not an outright false statement.

Comment: Some landlords do not want to deal directly with tenants, instead preferring to deal with other professionals.

Comment: Do you (the tenant) have to pay the agent's fee, or is the agent asking the landlord to pay the fee?

Comment: @TTT Tenant usually pays Agent in the amount of one month's rent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would Landlord lease to only Tenants represented by Estate Agent?

It's probably not the case that they would always *only* lease to tenants who are represented, but when the demand for rental space is normal or better, the Landlord can be more selective with their tenants, and they may believe having professional representation can reduce their risk. This is especially true if the tenant is paying the realtor fee as both the tenant and realtor have some "skin in the game".

**An anecdotal example:** I was renting a house when I purchased a new one, and  there were a few months left on my lease when I moved. My landlord agreed to start looking for tenants with his realtor, and agreed that I could do the same, and if either of us found him a tenant who could move in before my lease ended I wouldn't have to pay for that portion of the lease. I found 3 candidates. One of them was represented by a realtor but said the landlord would have to pay 1 month rent to have this candidate. My landlord wasn't going to pay the fee and it ended up being on me to pay it, but since this candidate couldn't move in until the final month of my lease, it was pointless for me to pay it, so I turned that candidate down. My landlord turned down my other two candidates:

1. Candidate 1 had verifiable income but a poor credit score.
2. Candidate 2 was a foreigner, had no credit score at all, but was willing to pay the entire year's lease up front. (Apparently this is pretty common in the person's native country of South Korea.)

In both cases my landlord turned them down because they were too risky. I was surprised by the second one, as I thought that paying up front eliminated the risk, but he said what if they want to renew the lease, and perhaps more telling was that he said, "It's just weird."

The landlord was using a realtor of his own to find candidates, and ended up finding someone to move in for the final month of my lease so I saved 1 month rent. Note that my landlord paid for his realtor (presumably 1 month rent) and *still* preferred to pay that extra fee for the peace of mind provided by his own realtor's candidates.

> Why did Landlord lie to Tenant, when Tenant was unrepresented?

I agree with [nanoman's comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152587/why-would-landlord-lease-to-tenant-when-represented-by-agent-but-not-directly-t/152621#comment310189_152587) that it wasn't *exactly* a lie, though it was extremely misleading. It's probably just the generic answer they give to everyone that they reject, regardless of the reason.

Comment: "I was surprised by the second one, as I thought that paying up front eliminated the risk".  The people who have enough money to pay a year's rent in advance are often drug dealers looking for a new site for a cannabis farm or drug factory.  That's a very big risk for a landlord.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate *"they may believe having professional representation can reduce their risk"**? Why does a represented Tenant reduce Landlord's risk? The agent isn't a surety or guarantor! The agent isn't personally guaranteeing the rent!

Comment: @Guest note I purposefully said, "they may *believe* having professional representation can reduce their risk", since I'm not sure that it actually does. Some of the risks landlords face are tenants lying on their application, or wasting their time when they're not actually going to pull the trigger on the lease. When a tenant is willing to pay a realtor for representation, it shows they are serious about renting (similar to paying an application fee), and now there's also another person who is (to some extent) willing to put their professional reputation on the line on behalf of the tenant.

Comment: @Guest another way to think about it is, when applying for a job, you may list some personal references who are friends, but also professional references with whom you worked. The professional references are arguably worth more to a recruiter than friends.